# Why is the Mongolian Horse superior in stamina?

Tags: dna, zoology, physiology

I've heard a lot about the [Mongolian Horse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolian_horse) over the years, especially that it has more stamina than the Arabian Horse. It's a little smaller/lighter than an Arabian.

- Apparently the Mongol Horse can outlast an Arabian, despite having a lower top speed, due to stamina. **NOTE:** I could not find a good source for this, especially when talking about medieval times. It's very hard to find a true apples-to-apples comparison, because of things like a heavy Knight vs a lightly-armored Mongol, and back then Arabian horses were a little different anyway.
- The Mongolian Horse can subsist on grass alone, whereas the Arabian Horse needs a lot of oats if its gonna do heavy hauling or riding.
- The Mongolian Horse doesn't need horseshoes, since for some reason the hoof doesn't wear down much over its lifetime.

[Source 1](http://www.theadventurists.com/the-jibber/29/1/2014/the-horses-of-the-mongol-derby), [Source 2](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3446571/Mongolian-cowboys-riding-skills-forefathers.html)

I would like to know, **what biological differences** can explain this? Do they have a different kind of muscle? Is their heart or lungs significantly different? Bones?

And the granddaddy point: What percentage difference exists between the DNA of a Mongolian Horse versus an Arabian Horse? For reference, the difference between a human and a chimp is [about 1.2%](http://humanorigins.si.edu/evidence/genetics) .

Comment: This question appears a bit broad. You should consider narrowing it down.